# NGINX serves Pterodactyl php file as download instead of rendering it

Tags: php, nginx

I was trying to get Pterodactyl running alongside PhpMyAdmin on the same domain, but different paths on that doman, so that organising/managing this domain is easier for HTTPs and stuff.
I tried several things, but this one is the thing that got me closest to my result.

`sub.example.com` file:

```
server {
    server_name sub.example.com;
    root /var/www/sub.example.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    # location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    # location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    # PhpMyAdmin
    location ^~ /phpmyadmin {
        auth_basic "Admin Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_pass;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

    # This is the actual Pterodactyl path (code)
    location ^~ /pterodactyl {
        alias /var/www/sub.example.com/pterod/public;

        access_log off;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/pterodactyl.app-error.log error;

        client_max_body_size 100m;
        client_body_timeout 120s;

        sendfile off;

        location ~ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 100M \n post_max_size=100M";
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
            fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = sub.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name sub.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

| PHP Version | php8.2-fpm.sock exists? | Ubuntu Version | NGINX Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8.2.6 | Yes | Ubuntu 22.04 | nginx/1.18.0 |

The code for the `pterodactyl` path is directly from the [Pterodactyl Webserver Configuration](https://pterodactyl.io/panel/1.0/webserver_configuration.html#nginx-without-ssl) guide.

- The pteroq.service file is also installed and enabled.
- Redis works.
- Database works.

**Miscellaneous:**
`nginx.conf` file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Fast-cgi.conf in snippets:

```
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

If anyone can help me here, thanks in advance!

Comment: Update: It doesnt download anything anymore, but now the page is just...blank?

Answer (score 0):

It seems PHP files are not passing to fpm correctly. Also, there are several `location ~ \.php$` blocks and this could lead Nginx to some confusion.

[EDIT]

I've missed a config error in your original .conf file. You've set             `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;` on your `location ^~ /pterodactyl` block. It should probably be `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;` as you have in your other blocks.

I'd try this config:

```
server {
    server_name sub.example.com;
    root /var/www/sub.example.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # PhpMyAdmin
    location ^~ /phpmyadmin {
        auth_basic "Admin Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_pass;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

    # This is the actual Pterodactyl path (code)
    location ^~ /pterodactyl {
        alias /var/www/sub.example.com/pterod/public;

        access_log off;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/pterodactyl.app-error.log error;

        client_max_body_size 100m;
        client_body_timeout 120s;

        sendfile off;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 100M \n post_max_size=100M";
            fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
            fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server{
    if ($host = sub.example.com) {
        return 301 https://sub.example.com$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name sub.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Run `sudo nginx -t && sudo nginx -s reload` after commit changes to test the new config and reload nginx with it.

Comment: When testing it, it gets two errors.
One says that `location /` cant be used inside of `location ^~ /pterodactyl {`
The other says: `nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_index" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sub.example.com:61`

Comment: + idk how to fix that, since when i tried commenting that "fastcgi_index" duplicate line out it would again just download the PHP file rather than running it.
The error with `location /` was apparently fixed by replacing `/` with `~`, i don't know much about what `~` does in NGINX or what it changed, but the error is gone now. LMFAO

Comment: if you need the file structure of `/var/www/sub.example.com/pterod` or `/var/www/sub.example.com/pterod/public` you can ask me too

Comment: Could you edit your question and add snippets/fastcgi-php.conf file?

Comment: You are right. There is no need to duplicate the fastcgi_index param as you have an index directive on your root block. Try updated code on my answer and let me know.

Comment: Hi @CodingFox. I've missed an important point in my answer. Check edited and let me know.

Comment: Edited my question and it still for some reason only downloads a file???

Comment: Weirdly enough, other PHP pages like PHPmyAdmin ran totally fine (even before and now). so idk why pterodactyl is struggeling so much?

Comment: I will look into if i fucked something up with pterodactyl setup

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I've tested my config on a fresh Nginx install and works as expected. Good luck.